# SVN remove . from version control

Tags: svn

I accidentally added '.' to version control and then did `svn delete --keep-local .` to try and take it out of version control. which only made things worse. How can I:

1. correct this situation and
2. check in all files without issuing the command `svn ci . -m''`, which seems to add '.' to version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `svn ignore .` to exclude `.` from `check in` operation
2. `svn st` to verity changes before `check in`

I hope it helps you.